# Problem with Raku and SSL on Windows Machine

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, raku, cro

I just installed perl6 on windows server and windows 7.

I want to port a script which is already running on openbsd to a windows machine.

I tested this code:

```
my $resp = await Cro::HTTP::Client.get('https://www.perl6.org/');
```

And I'll get is this on both Windows machines:

```
C:\Users\Matthias\CommaProjects\testing>perl6 cro.pl6
Tried to get the result of a broken Promise
  in block  at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\0609EA0BB03C70C2C15DB4B144D704
1C1059D14C (Cro::TLS) line 108

Original exception:
    An operation first awaited:
      in block  at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\A4ECA701FE96A8456AEB83692D
6B3C55AAFC964C (IO::Socket::Async::SSL) line 322

    Died with the exception:
        Server certificate verification failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
          in block  at C:\rakudo\share\perl6\site\sources\A4ECA701FE96A8456AEB83
692D6B3C55AAFC964C (IO::Socket::Async::SSL) line 322
```

Does somebody can give an hint how to get this running?

Edit: I have also tested WWW with TLS which is running well:

```
use WWW;
say get 'https://httpbin.org/get?foo=42&bar=x', :SomeHeader<Value>;
```

Comment: TLS connections are working in general, as shown in my edit. cURL is working as well and also does openssl s_client -connect czds-api.icann.org:443.

Comment: Did `IO::Socket::Async::SSL` install easy for you? It won't install on my Win10 box.

Comment: You are right Holli. Installation (testing) fails also on my machines. I have already submitted the Issue to github: https://github.com/jnthn/p6-io-socket-async-ssl/issues

Answer (score 4):

It looks like, support for windows is not fully implemented in cro yet. But it seems to be planned for future releases according to the [roadmap](https://cro.services/roadmap). At least one of the cro dependencies has also an issue when used with windows [IO::Path::ChildSecure](https://github.com/perl6-community-modules/perl6-IO-Path-ChildSecure/issues/3).

As a workaround at the moment you can try to use the [cacert.pem](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) from the curl project placed in the current working directory together with your code:

```
use Cro::HTTP::Client;

#cacert.pem from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
constant %ca := { ca-file => 'cacert.pem' };
my $resp = await Cro::HTTP::Client.get('https://www.perl6.org/', :%ca);
say await $resp.body;
```

Answer (score 2):

It has been confirmed that there are some Issues in the corresponding library.
So I think this Feed here can be treated as solved. Further discussion will be happen on the github space of the lib:

https://github.com/jnthn/p6-io-socket-async-ssl/

Many thx to Jonathan there!